# ZSH escaping / file matching pattern

Tags: shell, shell-scripting, zsh

This works from command line:

```
scp -r ^.git b:/home/wopi/blyzics/.
```

when I paste the above line in a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
scp -r ^.git b:/home/wopi/blyzics/.
```

And run it

```
./deploy.sh
```

I get:

```
^.git: No such file or directory
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `^.filename` is a feature enabled only when `EXTENDED_GLOB` is set. You probably have this set in your `.zshrc` for interactive use, but a shell script won't be using this.

See the [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) for info. To enable this in your scripts you can simply run:

```
setopt extended_glob
```

at the top of your script. Note that this isn't portable, however.

Comment: No way for a shell script to use this option ?

I mean without pasting the setopt extendglob in each schell script ? (I have this option set in my shell)

Comment: For compatibility reasons most of these options aren't on by default, so if you want to use zsh for scripting you need to tell it to turn on zsh-specific options. There's nothing wrong with using `setopt` in a script.